# Eclipse SWT Text Boxes change size

Tags: java, layout, eclipse-plugin, swt

I had an Eclipse plug-in app (ten-year-old code, no documentation, etc.) dropped in my lap and while adding new features to it, I noticed that when a panel is resized, the text boxes change size continuously while the separator is being dragged.[image: This is what it should look like]

[image: After resizing]

As you can see in the second picture, the text boxes are kind of randomly sized.  Is there a setting in SWT that will prevent this from happening?

Here's how I'm creating one of the text boxes.  The others are basically clones of this:

```
    Font font = parent.getFont();
    setLayout(new FillLayout());

    SashForm sashForm = new SashForm(this, SWT.VERTICAL);

    FormToolkit toolkit = new FormToolkit(getParent().getDisplay());
    Section section = toolkit.createSection(sashForm,
            Section.DESCRIPTION | ExpandableComposite.TITLE_BAR | ExpandableComposite.EXPANDED);
    section.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));
    section.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    section.setText("Section Title");
    Composite controlComposite = toolkit.createComposite(section);
    GridLayout controlLayout = new GridLayout();
    controlLayout.numColumns = 2;
    controlLayout.verticalSpacing = 20;
    controlComposite.setLayout(controlLayout);
    section.setClient(controlComposite);

    Font bold = ResourceManager.getBoldFont(font);

    Label textLabel = toolkit.createLabel(controlComposite, "Title:", SWT.BOLD);
    GridData gd = new GridData();
    gd.horizontalSpan = 1;
    textLabel.setLayoutData(gd);
    textLabel.setFont(bold);

    textBox = new ExtendedText(controlComposite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.SINGLE, false);
    gd = new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL);
    gd.horizontalSpan = 1;
    gd.verticalSpan = 2;
    textBox.setLayoutData(gd);
```

The ExtendedText class is an extension of StyledText.  The important bits of it are this:

```
    GridData gd_bg = new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH);
    setLayoutData(gd_bg);

    final GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout();
    gridLayout.verticalSpacing = 0;
    gridLayout.marginWidth = 0;
    gridLayout.marginHeight = 0;
    gridLayout.horizontalSpacing = 0;
    gridLayout.numColumns = 1;
    gridLayout.makeColumnsEqualWidth = true;

    sashForm.setWeights(new int[] { 1, 1 });
```

Comment: You'll need to post the code that you use to create the `Text` objects and if there's code that handles resizing that you'll need to post that as well.

Comment: Good point.  I'll update in a bit

Comment: You are really going to have to show us a [mcve] because bits of code like this aren't enough. For example that last `gridLayout` doesn't do anything unless it is set as a control's layout somewhere. You seem to have a ViewPart containing a form and from the look if it a Section. There is a lot of interaction here that can't been determined from what you have shown.

Comment: I have to be careful about the code that I post (references to proprietary info).  I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @greg-449 I updated the code.  I hope it's enough

Comment: @ChrisClark It'll have to be an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as greg mentioned earlier, i.e. try to reproduce your issue in a standalone SWT application. Include as little code as possible, but as much as required.

Comment: I'll see what I can do.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after digging in a little deeper, I got it working as expected.

First, the controlComposite and controlLayout objects are now created using

```
Composite controlComposite = new Composite(section, SWT.NONE)
controlComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));
controlComposite.setBackground(section.getBackground());
GridLayout controlLayout = new GridLayout(2, true);
controlLayout.marginHeight = 20;
controlLayout.marginWidth = 0;
controlLayout.verticalSpacing = 10;
controlLayout.horizontalSpacing = 0;
controlComposite.setLayout(controlLayout);
section.setClient(controlComposite);
```

Once I did that, things started to stabilize.  I also ended up tweaking the weights to this:

```
sashForm.setWeights(new int[] { 2, 3 });
```

It's not perfect, but it'll do for now.

Thanks to @greg-449 and @Baz for taking a look